# Huawei Push Kit Messages is Delayed

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

CP is sending push from their server in Singapore using our REST API.

The users of these devices is located in China.

Push messages are delivered only after some delay

Answer (score 0):

HUAWEI Push Kit supports cross-region messaging, but the messaging performance may be affected. To minimize cross-region messaging, it is recommended that you deploy servers in regions where users gather.

Please refer the below link:
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/android-config-agc-0000001050170137#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001078601380__section3380135485

[image]